# Populate a mvc5 list?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-5.1

Right now I can create games under the Games/Create.
And I can make a post under Post/Create.

But my problem is that right now my `public int GameId { get; set; }` gets populated with the items that is in my Game table in my SQL database. Which is just fine that's how I like it.

But I want `public string Title { get; set; }` to the populated the same way with the values that are in the Game database.

`public int GameId { get; set; }` gets populated with a dropdownlist with the values that is in my Game table.

And as for `public string Title { get; set; }` I have to enter it manually. I want that to be populated the same way as `GameId`

**This is my Post Model**

```
public class Post
{
    [Key]
    public int PostId { get; set; }

    //URL
    [Display(Name = "URL")]
    [StringLength(80)]
    public string Url { get; set; }
    //User
    [Display(Name = "User")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    //Game
    [Display(Name = "Game")]
    public int GameId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Next Game")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual Game Game { get; set; }

    //Time
    private DateTime? _date;
    public DateTime? Date
    {
        get
        {
            if (_date == null || _date.ToString() == "1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM")
            {
                return _date = DateTime.Now;
            }
            return _date;
        }
        set
        {
            _date = value;
        }
    }
```

**And this is my Game Model**

```
    public class Game
{
    [Key]
    public int GameId { get; set; }

    //Game
    [Display(Name = "Game")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    //User
    [Display(Name = "User")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: public int GameId { get; set; } gets populated in a droplist with the values that is in my Game tabel.

And as for public string Title { get; set; } I have to enter it manualy. I want that to be populadated the same way as GameId

Comment: you want Title to populated where and in which control? show your controller action and View relevant with this model

Comment: Your dropdownlist should bind to `GameId` but display `Title` (and why would you have property `public string Title { get; set; }` in the `Post`?)

Comment: Because it's the orginal plan is to have it, You choose the game you upload, and than 'Title' is going to be the next game you are going to upload. Poorly named which I've now fixed.

Comment: This is like the 4th post from different users about the same code. I dont get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you don't need your property Title in your Post Model, in your controller you can do something like this to get all data of Game.

```
using (var db = new YourDbContext())
{
    var post = db.Posts().Include(g => g.Game).FirstOrDefault();
    var gameTitle = post.Game.Title;
}
```